# Bazel build with Jackson annotations for ser/Deser and generate Java classes

Tags: java, jackson, bazel, annotation-processing

So, we have been trying to xploring bazel as a build system for our organization, since we have a huge monorepo.
One of the problems I'm facing is, we have some code-gen classes which use Jackson's annotation processors to generate immutable copies of some file types.

Eg :

```
@JsonSerialze
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as=ImmutableABC.class)
Public abstract class ABC {
...
}
```

So, for this , I include a java_plugin tag in bazel build file for this module as follows :

```
Java_plugin(
        name="abcgen",
        srcs=["src/.../ABC.java"],
        Deps=[ {jackson-deps go here}],
        processor_class = "org.immutables.processor.ProxyProcessor",
)
```

This always fails , saying cannot find the ImmutableABC.class file which is referenced in the annotation.
Any ideas? Am I missing the processor class for the Jackson annotations, and also is it possible to include multiple processor classes?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing issues as such, ensure generates_api = 1 for your plugin, if the generated classes are used in the library, as for the jackson part, that wasn't really the problem